# Convert every 5 bits into integer values in C++

Tags: c++

Firstly, if anyone has a better title for me, let me know.

Here is an example of the process I am trying to automate with C++

I have an array of values that appear in this format:
9C07 9385 9BC7 00 9BC3 9BC7 9385

I need to convert them to binary and then convert every 5 bits to decimal like so with the last bit being a flag:

I'll do this with only the first word here.

9C07

10011 | 10000 | 00011 | 1

19 |   16 |    3

These are actually x,y,z coordinates and the final bit determines the order they are in a '0' would make it x=19 y=16 z=3 and '1' is x=16 y=3 z=19

I already have a buffer filled with these hex values, but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: I suggest using “integer” instead of “decimal” for less ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume these are integer literals, not strings?

The way to do this is with bitwise right shift (>>) and bitwise AND (&)

```
#include <cstdint>

struct Coordinate {
        std::uint8_t x;
        std::uint8_t y;
        std::uint8_t z;
        constexpr Coordinate(std::uint16_t n) noexcept
        {
                if (n & 1) { // flag
                        x = (n >> 6) & 0x1F; // 1 1111
                        y = (n >> 1) & 0x1F;
                        z = n >> 11;
                } else {
                        x = n >> 11;
                        y = (n >> 6) & 0x1F;
                        z = (n >> 1) & 0x1F;
                }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would extract the three coordinates and the flag from the 16 least significant bits of `value` (ie. its least significant word).

```
int flag = value & 1; // keep only the least significant bit
value >>= 1; // shift right by one bit
int third_integer = value & 0x1f; // keep only the five least significant bits
value >>= 5; // shift right by five bits
int second_integer = value & 0x1f; // keep only the five least significant bits
value >>= 5; // shift right by five bits
int first_integer = value & 0x1f; // keep only the five least significant bits
value >>= 5; // shift right by five bits (only useful if there are other words in "value")
```

What you need is most likely some loop doing this on each word of your array.